# Join two queries and group by two fields from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have those queries

```
SELECT CA_id, item_id, item_Cant, item_desc FROM items WHERE CA_id = 135
```

[image]

```
SELECT CA_id, prov_name, unitval, totval FROM provprices WHERE CA_id = 135 AND prov_name = 'SITECH'
```

[image]

and I want to join this two results, just like:

item_id - item_Cant - item_desc - unitval - totval

I tried diferent forms but the max that i can get is:
(If you notice the result from second table is dublicated, should be like the second image )

```
SELECT items.item_id,items.item_Cant,items.item_desc,provprices.unitval,provprices.totval 
FROM items,provprices 
WHERE items.CA_id = provprices.CA_id
AND provprices.prov_name = 'SITECH' 
AND items.CA_id = '135' 
GROUP BY items.item_id
```

[image]

If i change to `GROUP BY provprices.unitval` the duplicated result now is the first one

[image]

I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY`? You're not aggregating anything.

Comment: If not gives me http://imgur.com/b7fIdqZ and I want the selected in yellow

Comment: You're asking for every combination between the two subqueries. How is it supposed to know which ones it should return? I think you need another column to join by that relates them.

Comment: @Barmar You right, I need that, now works fine, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand so much, but try this,

**How do you wanna calculate the unitval and the totval**

```
       select item_id, item_Cant, item_desc, AVG(unitval), sum(totval)
        from (
             SELECT CA_id, item_id, item_Cant, item_desc
             FROM items
             WHERE CA_id = 135
        ) A
        inner join (
             SELECT CA_id, prov_name, unitval, totval
             FROM provprices
             WHERE CA_id = 135 AND prov_name = 'SITECH'
        ) B ON A.CA_id=B.CA_id
GROUP BY item_id, item_Cant, item_desc
```

Comment: That gives me double result, the correct is the resalted in yellow http://imgur.com/TDUroYv

Comment: This is equivalent to his original query.

Comment: aaa ok, now i fix. but how do you want calculate the last 2 columns?

Comment: Doesn't works, in unitval, totval gives a diferent number than the original. I just want the first table and the second table joined, but now i fix it, I add another column to provprices for relates them. Thanks so much for your help.